# AngularJs Select Option binding Issue shared modal

Tags: c#, angularjs, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue where between two pages I am sharing a modal, both pages are using the same angularJs version(v1.2.14), and both pages call the exact same directives (ui.select2). The select box inside of the modal works on one page, whilst on the other it simply stay as the default option.

As an fyi I have tried implementing the select box in different styles e.g. ng-repeat on the options, and not using the track by. This however results in the other pages selecting options to break. I can only ever get one page to work and the other to break.

The strange thing is that in the background the bound value is updating correctly:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <select ui-select2="{width: '100%'}" class="form-control" 
     ng-model="Model.DocumentTypeId" 
     ng-options="documentType.DocumentTypeId as documentType.DocumentTypeDescription for documentType in Model.DocumentTypes track by documentType.DocumentTypeId">
         <option value="">Select Document Type</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

If you have any suggestions of why this is occurring it would be great.

Here is a heavily truncated view of the controller:

```
module Views.TMDocumentUpload {
    export class DocumentUpload implements IDocumentUpload {
        public static SetupDocumentUploadDialog = "onSetupDocumentUploadDialog";

        public Init(model: DocumentUploadViewModel) {
            var self = this;

            if (self.$scope.Model.HideDocumentType || self.$scope.Model.DocumentTypeId == null) {
                if (self.$scope.Model.DocumentTypes.length == 1) {
                    self.$scope.Model.DocumentTypeId = self.$scope.Model.DocumentTypes[0].DocumentTypeId;
               }
            }
        }

        constructor(public $scope: IDocumentUploadScope, $http: ng.IHttpService, $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
            $scope.isAllSelected = true;
            $scope.ShareConfig = [];
            $scope.Model.DisplayShareOptions = false;
            $scope.Init = () => {
                var self = this;
                $scope.$on(DocumentUpload.SetupDocumentUploadDialog,
                    (e: ng.IAngularEvent, args?: Views.TMDocumentUpload.DocumentUploadViewModel) => {
                        self.$scope.Model = new DocumentUploadViewModel();
                            $http.get("/GetInitialModel")
                                .success(function (data: DocumentUploadViewModel) {
                                    angular.extend(data, args);
                                    self.Init(data);
                                });
                    });
            };
    }
}
DocumentUpload.$inject = ["$scope", "$http","$timeout"];
}
```

Comment: When you say sharing a modal, do you actually mean a modal window or the data model? If you do me modal window then are you storing the data model somewhere and loading it back between modal windows or passing the data along somehow?

Comment: I am sharing the modal window, this has an ng-controller which on initialization will call back to the server to check what document types a user can enter. The data is not shared.

Comment: So you are calling the server to get the data? Are you passing back the updates from changes made in the first modal so the second modal can access it?

Comment: No Sorry, the modals are separate instances, they are just to allow the user to upload a document. Neither page/modal window will go to the other.;

Comment: and yes i am calling the server to get the data, it returns a list of document types which the logged in user can see, at the moment I have set it up so it will always return the same list, to prove it isn't a server issue

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding you correctly now, it's just the fact the the options for the select do not show up the same between the modal windows on the different pages? Can you post the Controller code to see if it is something there?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I am trying to truncate the code so that it is only the relevant data (It is a root on select event page) there are around 30 functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by removing ui-select2, it seems that this was causing some sort of conflict with another directive in my second page.